# In Shopify how to add multiple products to cart with varying quantities via url

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

I know in Shopify you can add multiple products like this:

`/cart/add?id[]=VARIANT_ID1&id[]=VARIANT_ID2`

My question is how would you adjust the quantity of each product that's being added?

For example I wanted `VARIANT_ID1` to have a quantity of 2 and `VARIANT_ID2` to have a quantity of 1?

I tried this:

`/cart/add?id[]=VARIANT_ID1&quantity=2&id[]=VARIANT_ID2&quantity=1`

But it just made the quantity 1 for everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

There was an update to the AJAX API that allows now to add multiply variants with different quantities with the same request.

Example:

```
fetch('/cart/add.js', {
    method: "post",
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        items: [
            {
                id: 33116502556724,
                quantity: 5
            },
            {
                id: 33116502589492,
                quantity: 3
            }
        ]
    })
})
```

#### Old Answer

You can't use the quantity as a separate item for each variant.

You have a few options but they all have some cons.

Please refer to this doc for the requests: https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/getting-started/using-ajax-api

#### Using `/cart/add.js`

You can create multiply AJAX request and add each separate item as a new AJAX request.

**Pros:**

- it won't affect the products in the cart if they are already present

**Cons:**

- Too many AJAX requests

---

#### Using `/cart/update.js`

You can make a single request and pass different quantity to each variant.

**Pros**

- Save all variants with a single AJAX request with different quantity

**Cons**

- You will overwrite the quantity of the product if they are already added in the cart

---

So the solution may be to get the `cart.js` response check if the current variants are present and if they are then make an `update.js` while adding the quantity to the existing one. So it's not so straightforward.

I can't think of an easier solution but at the end you might need a minimum of 2 AJAX calls to add a different quantity.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by using the below code snippet:

`/cart/update?updates[VARIANT_ID1]=quantity&updates[VARIANT_ID2]=quantity`

Comment: Almost the perfect solution, but it replaces whatever quantity is already in cart. So, can be problematic.

Comment: Yes that is one drawback @ChrisHayes. Do you have any workaround for that?

Comment: I ended up using `/cart/update?updates` in combination with [GET /cart.js](https://shopify.dev/api/ajax/reference/cart#get-cart-js) to avoid hanging "Add to Cart" on a couple requests. So, on page load it gets the items in cart and updates the button with the right quantity. But still not perfect if someone is adding to cart in multiple tabs without refreshing pages. Ugly workaround is to get the cart state every X seconds.

Comment: Ya got it! That's the thing, there is no neat and perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

The easier way is to use Shopify Permalinks.

A cart permalink takes your customers directly to the first page of the checkout screen with items pre-loaded into their cart.

This is what a cart permalink looks like:

```
http://your-store.myshopify.com/cart/70881412:1,70881382:1
```

Where 70881412 is the product variant's unique ID and 1 is the quantity.

So the format of the url is:

```
http://yourstore.com/cart/#{variant_id}:#{quantity}(,...)
```

Comment: Works great, but skipping the cart page is not desirable for most sites.