# Adding 3 products to cart at the same time with Shopify liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'd like to create a button on Shopify product page which can add 3 products (quantity value =3) to the cart. I don't want to use shopify apps, but I am not sure if there's any way to add it using liquid code/js.

Comment: Need to add the same product quantity to 3 or 3 different products? not much cleared from your question?

Comment: You may try something like this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67311125/6578256, the link being wrapped in an href tag

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your product template you should find the add to cart form. Inside the form, there is whether an hidden input whether a quantity select with name "quantity". If that's an hidden one, simply set its value to 3, if that's a visible quantity input or select, replace it by:

```
<input type="hidden" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="3">
```

To prevent issues, make a copy of your theme before updating it.