# Shopify URL to add multiple items with discount code and utm parameters

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-template, shopify-activemerchant

I want to create the Shopify url to add multiple SKUs, apply a discount code, have utm parameters AND redirect to /cart NOT /checkout.

By the way, I stick to URL to solve the issue. I know Script Editor can block coupon and create discount on specific products.  However I don't want to use ScriptEditor instead of coupon code because I don't want customers to use some discount codes in addition to ScriptEditor discount.

Based on the articles below, I could create the URL which achives

1. add multiple items
2. apply discount code or leads to /cart
3. set utm parameter

examples
(1)This skips /cart and goes to /checkout
(please remove []  when you try)

https://[yourdomain.com]/cart/[variants_id1]:1,[variants_id2]:1?discount=[discount_code]&utm_campaign=spot_email

(2)This leads to /cart but does NOT apply a discount code
(please remove 【】 when you try)

https://【yourdomain.com】/cart/add?id[]=【variant_id1】&id[]=【variant_id2】&quantity[]=1&quantity[]=1&discount=【discount_code】&utm_campaign=spot_email
※please remove 【】 when you try

Does anyone know a URL scheme for that?

※articles
[Shopify community article](https://community.shopify.com/c/technical-q-a/cart-pre-filled-url-does-not-seem-to-be-able-to-add-more-than-2/m-p/506953?advanced=false&collapse_discussion=true&filter=location&location=forum-board:technical-qa&search_type=thread),
[Stack overflow artile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55986572/in-shopify-how-to-add-multiple-products-to-cart-with-varying-quantities-via-url)

Answer (score 0):

I've looked far and wide to get UTM's to attach during the cart, but I haven't found a solution. However, if you're looking to get a discount attached to /cart, here's your solution:

https://shopifyurl.com/discount/SAVE15?redirect=/cart/add?id=variant1&id=variant2

Adding UTM's to the end of it will just be removed after the items get added and the redirection kicks in. I found a thread in Shopify about someone being able to achieve this with an app called ZipLink. (I have not tested so good luck)

Hope Shopify implements a fix the future.

Comment: Hey, lenny
Thank you for your answer. I understand it's impossible now. But I didn't know ZipLink, so I want to try it to achive adding multiple items and apply discounts with utm parameters. 
100% agree with you. I expect Shopify's implementation on it!